# Java DB Table inheritance?

Tags: java, database

Is it possible to do Table Inheritance in Java DB? We have a complex code model that uses inheritance and would also benefit from DB inheritance.

Is it possible? It doesn't seem possible from a quick google or a poke around in netbeans.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question is fairly vague in the details. The more specific you are the better the community can support you. So I'm going to guess what support you are looking for and hope it helps.

If you're using something like JPA/Hibernate, you can create classes with the annotation `@MappedSuperClass`. When the classes are scanned, the relationship between a 'parent' table and a child table will be realized. As a quick example:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class Foo {
    private Long id;
    // ... getters and setters
}

@Table("BAR")
@AttributeOverride(name="id" column=@Column(name = "BAR_ID"))
public class Bar extends Foo {
    // ... map your table
}
```

If you'll notice, the `Foo` class does not have to represent a table. It can just provide some of the common fields that span across a number of tables (typical fields like modified_by, modified_date, etc.). If `Bar` has an id like BAR_ID, you can then override the parent with an `@AttributeOverride` annotation.

While I did everything with annotations, I'm sure you can look into doing this with XML as well.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. I'm not entirely sure what solution im using, although I think its Apache Derby and I am currently following this tutorial:http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db-custom.html. I wondered if using this way it would be possible to do Inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "Java DB Table" you mean a standard SQL table, accessed via JDBC, and not a product called "Java DB Table".
The answer to your question is that no, you cannot directly do inheritance in SQL.  This is not a limitation of Java, JDBC or any object-relational mapping tool, but an issue with SQL itself.
However, using Hibernate/JPA/JDO it's fairly easy to fake doing it, using several different methods.
So the answer to the question "Can I easily represent my really cool object iheritance hierarchy in a relational database using Java?" is, for suitable definitions of easy, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly .... :-(

---

Using an ORM solution like Hibernate (or JPA), you can have an abstract (or not) entity that has several subclasses, each mapped to a different table.

Advantages:

- You only define once each column, and reuse it for all tables.
- You can have some code that is generic to all these entities, if it relies on the common part.
- Hibernate also lets you write queries that are generic
  (example : "`select * from Object`" returns the whole database, as it matches all your entities).